# How to use special characters in footnote numbering within Word

Tags: academic-writing, footnotes, microsoft-word, numerals

I'm using Microsoft Word 2016 for formatting my paper. I'm trying to use different footnote numbering sequences for the title page and main body. More specifically, I want to use special characters such as *, #, etc., for footnotes appearing in the title page, and the usual Arabic numbers for footnotes appearing in the main body. For an example of footnotes in the title page, see below.
[image]

Let me further clarify what I'm trying to do: It doesn't have to be the title page. Consider this: You want to have the special character footnote numbering for the first two sections of your paper, and start the footnote numbering anew from the third section through the end of the paper. The first numbering sequence doesn't have to be the special character; it can be the Arabic numbering. The point is that you are starting a new footnote numbering sequence afresh at some page of your paper.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE ppp, glad you found us.  We have a [tour] and [help] you might wish to check out.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question.  I did a light edit and hopefully didn't change the meaning.  Please re-edit if I did.  If you're asking about footnotes, how is that relevant to the title page?  Because a title page won't have footnotes.  Or are you talking about numbering the pages themselves?  In that case, one does not number the title page (or the TOC).  Could you edit your post to clarify?  Thanks!

Comment: @Cyn: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question for a clarification and added a figure for an example of what I mean by footnotes in my title page.

Comment: Thanks for editing and for the screenshot.  I have never seen this style before, and I've written/read a lot of academic papers.  Are you sure this is something you must do?  Now I have seen contact information, dept info, and acknowledgments on the title page (in a book they properly belong on an internal page before the body) but never ever with a footnote marker on the byline.  The title page is short enough that it's dead obvious what you're annotating.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want different page number in footer of your Title (and other introductory) page(s) and your main content.

Comment: @Cyn: Yes, I've been writing a lot of paper and that formatting is very common in my field. I have added an explanation for a further clarification right below the screenshot. And I deliberately made the screenshot short to save the space.

Comment: Nodding.  That's why I'm doing this in comments, because I know your question is about different sections of the paper and not so much about the title page.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/359187/how-to-use-footnotes-and-endnotes-in-microsoft-word/) guide, which uses Microsoft Word 2016 for its screenshots (but things shouldn't have changed too much for other versions), you can restart footnote numbering for each section of your work, and you can pick the number format separately for each section.

To open the footnotes configuration menu:

[image]

Within that menu, to restart the footnotes numbering for each section:

[image]

To use different numerals:

[image]

Comment: Well you've covered it all :-)  I did a quick Google to check what was out there and thought maybe I'd write it up, but you've done a great job with it.

Comment: @Galastel & Cyn: Thanks so much for your help! In fact, I have already tried this solution. But it makes footnote numbering restart for each section. What I need is to restart the footnote numbering again only once. For instance, I have two sequences of footnote numbering; one for sections 1 through 3 and another one for thereafter.